# IIS 7 still serves default page on port 80 when I change ports

Tags: iis-7, bindings

IIS 7 site xxx.com.

Binding:

**IP address** 10.149.120.80

**Port** 8089

**Hostname** xxx.com

Created DNS record:
xxx.com – 10.149.120.80

Site opens when typing URL: "xxx.com:8089" but when trying to reach "xxx.com" I just get IIS 7 default page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Nothing, that is normal behaviour. When openning http://example.com you try to reach it via default port (80). When you specify the port (eg. 8089 - http://example.com:8089/, you connect to that port. You have the default IIS listening on port 80, and your page is on 8089.

Comment: @mulaz Great. Is there any possibility to set up another behavior: example.com, configured on IIS to run on 8089 port - open without typing port to address bar? To hide this port. Not Javascript.

Comment: Directly... no. You can set up a proxy infront of your webserver, to forward the requests to the webserver on any port. Is there any special reason to use the non-standard port?

Comment: @mulaz Thanks. I do not know exactly... maybe you can advice. There are 2 Virtual Directories and 3 Applications existing under "Default Web Site". Whether there are any risks placing my new site (consisting of one html page that links to a few flash elements to the root of "Default Web Site"?

Comment: Sorry, I am not that fammiliar with IIS... with Apache etc., you just use a different virtualhost for each page.